# How to allow users to upload images, and have the file be their name in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, multer

So I'm currently attempting to create an avatar upload system with `Express.js` and `multer` but whenever I go and put it through the form it returns the error.

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (D:\Express\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Multipart.<anonymous> (D:\Express\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:107:7)
    at Multipart.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at HeaderParser.cb (D:\Express\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:358:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (D:\Express\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:162:20)
    at SBMH.ssCb [as _cb] (D:\Express\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:394:37)
    at feed (D:\Express\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:248:10)
    at SBMH.push (D:\Express\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:104:16)
    at Multipart._write (D:\Express\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:567:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
```

**Here is some of the code that I used call** `multer`

```
const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({ dest: 'img/users' });
```

**Router for parsing the image:**

```
router.post(
  "/edit/image/parse",
  upload.none(),
  function (req, res, next) {
    next();
  },
  upload.single("avatar"),
  function (req, res, next) {
    res.end("done!");
  }
);
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="/edit/image/parse/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <button class="login" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So my question is how do I solve this error, and then how do I upload it, then change the filename to match the users username?

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Comment: I actually found that if I use upload.any, it actually works. I tried the answer and it just returned the same error ive had.

Comment: I do not think so ...:-) I've checked this solution (docs ref) and it's working perfectly fine...;-)  But never mind ! Best regards !

Answer (score 0):

Crucial point and example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer reference:

**Form**

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

---

**Express**

```
const express = require('express')
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

const app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
}) ....
```

The `NAME` attribute of your `input` must be the same as he parameter name passed in `upload.single('attr')`.

---

In Your case it shluld looks like :

```
upload.single("avatar")
```

**Input**

```
 <input type="file" name="avatar">
```